# SQL query based on today's date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, date-arithmetic

I have a query which I got help with last night but I am stuck on another bit.

The code I have is

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON b.status_id=a.id 
GROUP BY status_id
```

What I would like to do now is only show results if they have been entered on today's date? The date column is in `table2`. The format for the date column is date and time (eg 1341241153) but I only need to check if the date matches the current day.  I hope that is clear.

Any help will be gratefully received!

EDIT: this is a MySQL database.  I have tried all the solutions so far and nothings worked.  Sorry for not being clearer!!

FINAL EDIT: The question was not clear enough so I posted again in order to get a quick response.  The new question with complete solution can be seen here [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492823/return-results-of-query-based-on-todays-date-in-sql-mysql)

Comment: What sort of datetime format is `134124115`?  I'm guessing that it's the 13th of April this year but who can tell?  It might just as well be the stardate for the captain's log.  If you're not going to use an actual date/datetime datatype to store calendrical information you *must* keep to a strictly defined format.  Otherwise you're data is just rubbish.

Comment: I don't know the date format to be honest it is what the CRM uses automatically when an entry is made

Comment: If *you* don't know what the date format is why do you expect *us* to?  And let's be clear about this, if you don't know the format there is absolutely zero possibility of separating the date element from the time element.  So you need to start asking around, reading the manual or googling for that crucial info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you `group`you need a `having` instead of a `where`:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON b.status_id=a.id 
GROUP BY status_id
having b.date  = 1341241153
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function to do this if you do it quite often, but here's some code that flattens any date passed in to it:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a ON b.status_id=a.id 
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, a.DateColumn)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY status_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which database type this is, if it is Oracle you just need to truncate the date:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON b.status_id=a.id 
WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) = TRUNC(b.dateColumn)
GROUP BY status_id
```

If it is MySQL or MSSQL the syntax is slightly different, but similarly simple.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2008 you can use this:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON b.status_id=a.id 
WHERE dateValue BETWEEN 
   CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
GROUP BY status_id
```

Comment: This is going to sound a little odd but I've personally found that if you are going to do it this way you can get a better Query Plan that allows for parrallelism if you take the functions out so Declare a StartDate Date and a EndDate Date. Then set them equal to: StartDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and EndDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) You then the Where be: WHERE dateValue BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate . I've found it helpful when SQL can actually use more cores on some of the Queries here. Wanted to note that. Variables would have @ on them. Stupid Edit said it took 5 minutes to type this.

Comment: @Cericme did you know that you can delete comments? Also you can use backticks ` in comments e.g. `StartDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and EndDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks. The Delete button wasn't showing for me the other day for some reason and I didn't know about the backticks in comments. So the SQL bits from my Original Comment were: `Declare @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date; SELECT @StartDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), @EndDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);` Then the Where Portion: `WHERE dateValue BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`